# Use of (em) dash immediately after dot - what difference does the dot make?

Tags: punctuation, dashes

The [first paragraph of chapter 112](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Moby-Dick_(1851)_US_edition/Chapter_112) of [Herman Melville’s famous 1851 novel,  ***Moby-Dick; or, The Whale***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby-Dick), concludes as follows:

> And so it was. — Most miserable.

Is it valid? Why not omit the dot, and have the following (what difference would it make)?

> And so it was — most miserable.

Comment: There are various choices of punctuation that Melville makes that would be considered unusual or non-standard today. 'Moby-Dick; or, The Whale' / 'The issue was, the loss of the extremities of both feet.' / 'He had been an artisan of famed excellence, and with plenty to do; owned a house and garden; embraced a youthful, daughter-like, loving wife, and three blithe, ruddy children; every Sunday went to a cheerful-looking church, planted in a grove. '

Comment: How could it possibly *not* be "valid"? Surely you are not asking whether a literary giant was somehow doing something "invalid", something "wrong", are you? Or do you just want to know whether you should follow in his footsteps in this style? The fickle fashionability of punctuation is much more like ever-changing tastes in hemlines and tie-widths than a timeless truth like the infinity of primes is.

Comment: @tchrist, 'valid' may not have been the best word to use, but surely it it reasonable for the OP to wonder whether this was **(1)** a departure from the standard use of dashes for which Melville had a special reason (and, if so, what that reason was), or **(2)** a quirk of Melville's, for which he had no special reason (but which we should tolerate because of the overall merits if his work), or **(3)** something that was done by other authors of the era, even though it is unusual nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment Edwin Ashworth wrote:

> There are various choices of punctuation that Melville makes that would be considered unusual or non-standard today. 'Moby-Dick; or, The Whale' / 'The issue was, the loss of the extremities of both feet.' / 'He had been an artisan of famed excellence, and with plenty to do; owned a house and garden; embraced a youthful, daughter-like, loving wife, and three blithe, ruddy children; every Sunday went to a cheerful-looking church, planted in a grove.'